# Не хватает памяти в ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32

Строю проект для работы приложения с ESP32 через API. Подключенные библиотеки для работы WIfFi, Http. Для настроек использовать хотел bluetooth. И в этом и вся проблема началась. Не хватает памяти. Либо делать настройку через API вместо BT, либо искать альтернативу ESP32 с большей емкостью, ну или подскажите какой нибудь еще другой вариант.

Comment: Возможно Raspberry Pi Pico больше соответствует требованиям вашего проекта.

Comment: В эту сторону еще не смотрел. Посмотрю, спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

bluetooth большая и суровая библиотека, для работы с wifi есть два варианта:

1. сам микроконтроллер как wifi-хост, вы обращаетесь к нему с настройкой
2. микроконтроллер как wifi-клиент периодически и при старте сам запрашивает данные для настройки, которые вы будете "оставлять" на веб-сервере в любом формате (json. xml, text) - это обычная практика для iot-устройств